# Angular, Service Unit Test. Waiting for observable value

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to perform simple unit test for BehaviorSubject. 
It looks like this:

```
   fit('pageChange', fakeAsync(() => {
        spyOn(pagintationService, 'pageChange');

        pagintationService.pageChange(3);

        expect(pagintationService.pageChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);

        tick(100);

        pagintationService.page$.subscribe(pageNum => {
            console.log(pageNum)
        })
    }))
```

When i log in susbscribe() I expect this value to be 3. That is becuase implementation looks like this:

```
  pageChange(page: number) {
        this.paginationPageSource.next(page);
    }
```

where

```
firstPage = 0;

    private paginationPageSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.firstPage);
    page$ = this.paginationPageSource.asObservable();
```

Why is that? I have tried also with flushMicrotasks() but nothing happens.

**UPDATE**

```
fit('pageChange', fakeAsync(() => {
        let pageNum = 3;

        spyOn(pagintationService, 'pageChange').and.callThrough();

        pagintationService.pageChange(pageNum);

        pagintationService.page$.subscribe(num =>
            expect(num).toBe(pageNum))

        expect(pagintationService.pageChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
    }))
```

Comment: Why is what? What's the problem? You've told what you expect. You haven't told what you observe.

Comment: I want to simulate action when paginationPageSource.next(page); will emit number (which is 3 here) and then check if page$ will contain this value.

Comment: OK. But that doesn't tell us what the problem is. But anyway: do you understand what a spy is. What happens when you call `spyOn(pagintationService, 'pageChange');`? Why do you spy on the method that you want to test?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, you're expecting console.log to fire and print out 3. Right now it won't because you listen to your observable AFTER you pass it a 3. In this case you need to listen to changes before you make the change, then it will behave as you're expecting.

The following will likely work as you're expecting.

```
it('pageChange', () => {
  const pagintationService: TestService = TestBed.get(TestService);
  let pageNum: number;

  spyOn(pagintationService, 'pageChange').and.callThrough();

  pagintationService.page$.subscribe(num => {
    console.log(`subscribe sees a ${num}`);
    pageNum = num;
  });

  pagintationService.pageChange(3);

  expect(pagintationService.pageChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
  expect(pageNum).toBe(3);
});
```

This will write out

```
LOG: 'subscribe sees a 0' // since behavior subject sends current value
LOG: 'subscribe sees a 3'
```

Also notice that I removed `fakeAsync` and `tick` as neither are necessary to make this work. You only need to use `tick` when time needs to pass, like for a debounce or `setTimeout`.